# hadoop How to mv files only if directory already exists in target location?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am trying to move data from one location to another location In Hadoop. I cant find solution where I can move files only if my target loaction already has the folder which I want to move.

EX:

```
source                                Target
/dir1/same_folder/path1file.txt    /dir2/same_folder/path2file.txt

After move command my output should look like this

Source folder 
/dir1/some_folder
Target folder
/dir2/same_folder/path1file.txt
/dir2/same_folder/path2file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. In HDFS you're provided with a command,

> hdfs dfs -moveFromLocal /local/file/path /hdfs/directory

I have tried the same in my cluster and it's working fine. In case you face any problem, let me know. I'll help you solve it.